# Why isn`t android studio letting me choose module to run project with?

Tags: react-native, android-studio, sdk

it doesn`t show modules here and when i press run it says : " error module not specified ".
any suggestions on what should i do ?

there is not much i thought of doing, also when im trying to run project using VS i get this when my expo is working perfectly, seems like this project is started using react native CLI? any suggestions on how to fix this ?  sry im pretty noob in this stuff

Comment: I cannot understand the question. Add a screenshot ?